# Remove characters in string in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following field that is calling the database `Phone_Number`. I would like to remove the `1-` when the number is displayed.

So instead of displaying `1-###-###-####`, I would like to display `###-###-####`.

I tried the following:

```
string x= Phone_Number;
x.Remove(0,1);
Response.Write(x);
```

However, it keeps displaying `1-###-###-####`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable in C# - [`String.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) call does not modify original string. It creates the *new string* in which specified characters are deleted and returns it. You should display result of this method call instead:

```
Response.Write(x.Remove(0,2)); // you should remove 2 characters
```

Or

```
Response.Write(x.Substring(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the result to x.  strings are immutable in C#:

```
x = x.Remove(0,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method would be:

```
if (x.StartsWith("1-")
    x = x.Remove(0,2);
```

This has the benefit of doing nothing if you get a phone number without the leading `1-`.

Thanks to commenter for pointing out my error.

Comment: Warning: what if telephone number has another occurrence of `1-`?

Answer (score 1):

As you see there are too many ways to remove substrings from strings. A new way that you can also use is a Regular Expression just in case the value you want to remove have a complex pattern in the future.

var x = phoneNumber;

var result = Regex.Match(x, @"^(1-)?(.*)$").Groups[2].Value;